# ¿Como realizar consultas a colecciones con campos embebidos en mongoose?

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express, mongoose

aprendiendo mongoose y mongoDB me surge un inconveniente que no tengo clara como resolver, con el siguiente codigo:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'); 

var mongooseEsquema = new mongoose.Schema({
    nombre: {type: String},
    apellido : {type: String},
    emb_lugares : [{type: new mongoose.Schema({
        localidad: {type: String},
        direccion: {type: String}
    })}]
});
var mongooseModelo = mongoose.model("informacion", mongooseEsquema);

//==================================================================
// docs de prueba almacenados en la coleccion informacion
// [
//     { 
//         nombre: "andres",
//         apellido:"perez",
//         emb_lugares: [
//           {localidad : "Barinas", direccion: "Av colonia # 3"},
//           {localidad : "Mazuela", direccion: "Av libertadoes # 45"},
//         ]
//     },
//     { 
//         nombre: "Sara",
//         apellido:"Gomez",
//         emb_lugares: [
//             {localidad : "Veraguas", direccion: "TR palmas # 85"},
//             {localidad : "Mazuela", direccion: "Av libertadoes # 45"},
//         ]
//     }
// ]

mongooseModelo.find({emb_lugares: {localidad : "Mazuela"}})
.then((dato)=>{
//...Devuelve  dato = null
})
.catch((error)=>{

});
```

al consultar a  MongoBD por todos los documentos cuyo campo   localidad     tenga el valor de    "Mazuela"   , me devuelve null (indicando que no encuentra coincidencias), sin embargo si realizo consultas básicas sobre campos sencillos (como el nombre o el apellido) funciona sin problemas pero en campos que contengan un  { type: new mongoose.Schema ()}    no sé cómo construir la consulta

Extendiendo un poco más la pregunta, ¿cómo puedo consultar campos (incluyendo los embebidos) en base a una expresión regular?

Gracias por cualquier aporte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accede por medio de la notación de punto, como si se accedieses directamente a los documentos anidados:

```
mongooseModelo.find({
  'emb_lugares.localidad': {
    $regex: /Ghost/,
    $options: 'i'
  }
})
.then((datos) => {
  // hacer algo
});
```

Ten en cuenta la clave `$options`; aquí puedes especificar el comportamiento de la expresión regular y pasarle las banderas que desees.

Comment: gugadev, le agradezco, acabo de hacer  algunas pruebas y funcionó correctamente. Lo único es que me a costado acostumbrarme a nombrar el campo como string   'emb_lugares.localidad' : {}  por que casi siempre se me olvidan las comillas.

Comment: De nada, colega. Lo que pasa es que ese string es separado para que se busque parte por parte (que viene a ser una key), por eso se especifica en forma de string. Saludos.

Comment: Buen día amigo, le agradezco una colaboración para no hacer toda una pregunta de un tema que creo que para la comunidad es trivial. ¿Como  puedo realizar una consulta sobre un documento embebido y que me retorne **únicamente** los datos que estoy consultando?; me explico mejor: si hago la consulta  `mongooseModelo.find({ 'emb_lugares.localidad' : 'Barinas' })`  la consulta si devuelve el documento correcto pero me devuelve **todos los datos del subdocumento**, hasta el momento he intentado con  `$elemMatch` pero me sigue entregando lo mismo, gracias